# how to repack logfiles with git efficiently

Tags: git, mysql, logfiles

I have several files on a server that grow permanently (logs, db-dumps, ..) and I want to make a full backup with history in a repository.

Simple diffs between two states are pretty small, the files themselves too, but somehow the git repository  becomes very large, almost 100 GB now.

I found the repack command, but it now runs for hours and I don't see how far it got already. Can I see somehow how much percent already got processed?

Also in the beginning there were some repack problems, so I have found the following parameters, not sure if those values are good for my use case:

```
repack -a -f -d --window-memory=400M --max-pack-size=400M --depth=100 --window=100
```

Is it possible to configure git to:

- .. work with each file individually? I read it sorts all files by size and type and if they are close, it does a diff on them, independent of the filename. Can this be disabled and to only check the same file? They are never renamed. I also thought about making one git for every file, but that will be a lot of repositories. Would that be usual?
- .. compare each new file only to the last 2-3 versions of the same file? Or even only to the last one? Since new content is only appendend, it doesn't make much sense to compare to earlier versions. For the db-dumps data could change in the middle, but it rarely does. The files are not really large, so I would prefer not splitting them.
- .. define an amout of commits before the files are stored fully again instead of diffs? Something like I-frames and P-frames in mpeg?
- Are the params I use good? Are there others I should use?

Final packed size is not that important as efficiency. So if it creates something like 2 GB instead of 1 GB that is fine (or is my max-pack-size limiting it to 400MB?!?), but it should not run for 10 hours if it can also do it in 10 minutes.

Every help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're probably storing binary files which don't diff well in Git, and that's why the history is increasing. You also don't say what's causing new git commits to be appended to the repository, which would be a factor. In general if you store large binaries in Git then you will get poor performance; it's just a matter of time.

Comment: Thx for the comment! There are only text files, largest one is around 200 MB. And the diffs are really small as they only contain the last added lines. The files are automatically added 4 times a day by a cronjob that does git add * && git commit -m "backup" && git push

Comment: I'm trying with different parameters the whole day, smaller depth/window, -A instead of -a, larger mem limits, but it just keeps running forever.

Comment: you could probably start a new repository by cloning the oldest revision, then packing, then updating to the next one, then packing, ...

Comment: that actually worked, thx!